# How to restrict same photo to be added again in custom album in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage,  self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

Using this method I can save image in photo album but not able to restrict to be saved same photo again in photo album

Comment: iOS doesn't have an out-of-the-box way to do this. You probably want some kind of algorithm to compare two images for exact matches (like byte-to-byte values comparison of their `NSData`), but then you need both pictures to compare on your hands. Which is a bit of a challenge if that first pic was saved long time ago.

Comment: IMHO compare bytes is the right way...

Comment: Please compare NSData object instead of comparing UIImage Object. NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1); 
NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);
return [data1 isEqualToData:data2];

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether file of same name exist at that path (Document-directory).

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString)
    paths = paths.appending("nameOfYourFile") as (NSString)
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths as String){
          //no such file exist at this path
          UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage,  self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil) 
    }
```